# How does one make a 3D background in a 2D game?

Tags: sdl, 2.5d

I am trying to figure out how to make a background that looks 3D in a game that is 2D. 
Below there is a video of the game "Under The Lotus." I am trying to get a background with similar effect (it looks like a 3D environment, while the game runs basically in the X and Y axis).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GsTwsx5aWo

Can anyone give me an idea how to do that? Or point me in some direction on what to read to be able to figure this out?

I am planning on using SDL for this game. If I could avoid using OpenGL that would be better, but it is not a real requirement.

Comment: That (assuming you mean clouds) looks like it's a pre-rendered background (a video), i don't see it reacting to the players position or the game in general.

Comment: Well, it seems to me those clouds are generated during runtime. Perhaps I am wrong, but what I am looking for is actually being able to have this effect of clouds (that I could generate during runtime), and not necessarily have the background react to the player position (at least no yet). Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Not familiar with SDL myself, but could you have several layers of differently sized transparent sprites scrolling small ones faster than large ones.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but I think it might be too slow. Might need to try out and see... There is not a specific design for that in the SDL API (not that I know at least), so I would have to blit in a specific order to the same surface (I can create an object with a Z-index for example, and bind from index 1 to index X).

Comment: I need to go to bed, but my answer would include using [homogeneous co-ordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) (X, Y, Z, W) for the center position of each cloud particle; but also reusing the W component of the position co-ordinate for the size of each particle.

Answer (score 1):

Like chrish said, I would recommend writing a game in a 3D engine or with a 3D framework than working with a 2D engine or framework and trying to add in 3D just for a single effect. OpenGL can do it, and so can many other game engines, like Unity (I would assume) and the BGE.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of 2D games are actually written using OpenGL (which is still a good option with SDL, actually); you can take advantage of the 3D hardware for creating very nice special effects without impacting your draw performance.

In a case like this, you'd draw your 3D background, switch to an orthographic projection, then draw your 2D bits on top. If I remember correctly, `glOrtho()` sets up the projection you want, and should be enough info to get you going (finding ortho tutorials is as simple as hitting up [the Google](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&sa=X&ei=9J6VTubHJKeGsgKWvLTvAQ&ved=0CBcQvwUoAQ&q=GLORTHO+tutorial&spell=1&biw=1181&bih=1029)). For example, [NeHe's Tutorial 21](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_21__25/25009/) shows you how to use `glOrtho()` for drawing 2D objects.

Comment: Great I will have a look into that. Perhaps it might clear some things up for me, and I can progress a bit with the result I want to get. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, using OpenGL/DirectX will give you more options and better performance for most things. It's definitely a lot more complex than SDL, but it will pay off.

The particular effect looks a pixel shader that uses noise (probably multiple times - first to find the coordinates in the noise, then to find the value). I was able to achieve a similar effect with this (HLSL, sorry):

```
sampler sNoise = sampler_state { texture = <_noise>; magfilter = ANISOTROPIC; minfilter = ANISOTROPIC; mipfilter = ANISOTROPIC; AddressU = MIRROR; AddressV = MIRROR; };
sampler sColors = sampler_state { texture = <_colors>; magfilter = ANISOTROPIC; minfilter = ANISOTROPIC; mipfilter = ANISOTROPIC; AddressU = BORDER; AddressV = BORDER; };

float4 background(PixelInfo p) : COLOR0
{
    float3 ofs = _time * _velocity + _ofs;
    float3 spos = float3((p.uv - ofs.xy) * 512 / _screenSize, ofs.z);

    float3 vpos;
    vpos.x = tex3D(sNoise, spos + 0.0000).r - 0.5;
    vpos.y = tex3D(sNoise, spos + 0.3333).r - 0.5;
    vpos.z = tex3D(sNoise, spos + 0.6667).r - 0.5;

    float v = tex3D(sNoise, vpos).r;
    return tex1D(sColors, pow(v, _density));
}
```

Comment: If it is not much to ask... is there a way you could share the whole source for that example? I am very interested on trying to compile and run it, and play around a bit to try to get the hang of this.

Comment: It's from an overly-ambitious XNA project of mine 2 years ago... If I can get it to compile, I will upload it later today.